# Update model.edmx not run in asp.net-mvc4

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I create a models.edmx in my project. The first it runs ok, after I insert `new table (Projects)` in SQLServer, then I update `models.edmx` by in diagram of `models.edmx` i right click chose update model from database, then in the diagram of `models.edmx` has projects table but in `models.tt` isn't Projects.cs and `models.context.cs` not has row `public DbSet<Project> Projects { get; set; }.` 
Where am i wrong and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correct and you want to have T4 templates (.tt) files to generate `public DbSet<Project> Projects { get; set; }`. I think you need to use the EF DbContext Generator, which can be done through the EDMX diagram -> right click -> Add Code Generation Item...

You need to download and install EF DbContext Generator.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove that model file from project, then again recreate it by the updated DB with same previous name. Simple